# <marquee> problem in ie8

Tags: html, css, marquee

My `<marquee>` tag is working perfectly in ie6 and ie7, but in ie8 it only shows first item.

How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: +1 just for using `<marquee>` in 2010, bravo.

Comment: Please don't use either `marquee` or `blink` for presenting text. It's not a good UI 'feature': http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marquee_element

Comment: `<marquee>` is a non-standard element. If IE finally dropped support for it, then Bravo for them. It is not cross browser and its not part of the HTML spec.

Comment: Does it *have* to be a `marquee`? Would you be amenable to sliding the element around with js/jQuery? That way if someone wants to view the page in a screen-reader/print it out then the content isn't hidden/obscured by default.

Comment: My answer below is for JavaScript, but is that what you are using for your development?  Or, what other tools/languages are you using in your design?

Comment: zend IDE for php- DW for frontend

Comment: @Mr.Waite:
  
I know this, modern browser, XHTML validation blah blah blah, Im not coming from behinds of mountain!! There is a site and the site have a marquee that not working in ie8, Im looking for a solution, a block like marquee!!!

Comment: Show us the code, then.  Can't bugfix it if'n we can't see it.

Comment: I think you should try nesting `<marquee>` within another `<marquee>`.

Comment: For some reason, a `<marquee>` in IE8 only scrolls to the edge of the screen, and then starts again, so the full length of it is not seen. The ideal solution is to drop the `<marquee>` tag, of course, but where this is not possible `header('X-UA-Compatible: IE=7')` or the equivalent `<meta>` tag works.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The marquee element is deprecated.  The W3C recommends using [`<em>` and `<strong>` as alternatives](http://www.contentquality.com/tutorial/j71.htm).  If you need to mimic the behavior of the marquee, JavaScript has tools for doing that.  [This discussion](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=151525) has a working JavaScript example.

Comment: "The marquee element is deprecated."
I know

Comment: Up-voted because a) I *loathe* the marquee 'feature,' and because b) obscuring/hiding/moving content with js means it's still available (non-obscured/hidden/moving) *without* js for accessibility.

Comment: @jasmine, there's a *reason* it's deprecated. It's a hideous non-feature that actively hinders successful UI.

Comment: I know, But there is a site and site owner want to every thing working perfect without jquery in ie6-7-8

Comment: Then your stuck if you can't use javascript, there is no equivelent tag that replaces marquee. How will the owner know your using javascript?

Answer (score 13):

As much as it pains me to link this:
http://remysharp.com/demo/marquee.html

A jquery based marquee which will work across browsers.

Comment: I up-voted the answer, since it answers the question, but **ugh**...it was an ethical *nightmare* to do so...freaking marquee...and I used to *like* Remy Sharp, too... =(

Comment: Im sorry, Im not familliar with these check and voting, 
I am looking for accepting question :(

Comment: Yeah, its pretty horrible, but the OP is tasked with maintaining a client's site from the sounds of it. However the `no javascript` condition makes it impossible.

Comment: There's the potential for a CSS3 solution, in my answer (somewhere around here), that, coupled with a `<noscript>` fall-back might allow this to work. It might even be possible to this option, with css3 and then fall-back to the traditional marquee for older browsers. Certainly if conditional comments are used to identify older versions of IE.

Comment: Are you sure you it's not too late to set the font-family to "Comic Sans" as well? That will make some people's heads totally explode:  http://blog.howdesign.com/2010/01/04/DesignerGang.aspx

Comment: I go through the link and download the js file. But I dont understand how to implement it for my <div>. Can u pls explain me.

Answer (score 4):

As much as I *loathe* the element and the vast majority of its use-cases, [CSS3 seems to have brought it back](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-marquee/):

- [CSS Play: CSS 3 Marquee](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menu/css3-marquee.html).
- [CSS3.info: CSS3 Marquee Module](http://www.css3.info/modules/css3-marquee-module/).

Comment: You're welcome; and now I'm going to go and wash my hands, eyes and mind in bleach... =p

Comment: It might seem like a good solution, but you'll never get this to work in any currently available version of IE.  It uses CSS3 animations that are only available with the -webkit prefix.

Comment: @derekerdmann, yeah, I know. I was posting for the purpose of providing extra information (since I think the accepted answer had been accepted prior to my posting this one). I'd've posted as a comment to that, or another, answer but I expected it to be unwieldy as a comment. And seriously? In this one case: *lucky, lucky IE (and non-Webkit) users* ... =b

Answer (score 3):

From what I understand Marquee is deprecated, and IE8 might be the version of IE that Microsoft decided to completely leave out support for that tag. Even if you do find a way to get it to work, I would suggest using another method to get the text to scroll (if that is what is needed) becuase you will probably have the same problem in the next version if IE.

**EDIT:** 
You can try java script...after a quick search I found this site that looks like it will generate the code for you. Also, since it's javascript it should now also work on Firefox, Chrome, etc. 
http://rumkin.com/tools/marquee/

Answer (score 0):

I really feel the scroller mechanism is pre-Web 2.0. If your client wants it, well you may not have a lot of options but I would really try and do some kind of demo to highlight that there are better ways and it would not cause any instability to the site if implemented correctly.

I know many clients are cautious, but in my experience if you can show them a better alternative which is as stable or even more stable and at a low cost (time and money) then they are willing to accept the new way more often than not.