# jQuery moving div plugin or how to

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey everybody. So, I have to create this thing at work where in a div, there's a lot of images and that div has to automatically move to left horizontally on page load. But, I'm not a JavaScript developer and i didn't find any plugins via google.

So if you know a solution or a plugin, please do tell.
All help is appreciated.

Comment: when you say move left, do you mean like dock left or somehting, OR, do you mean the images in it should move left like a marquee sort of thing...

Comment: have a look at this plugin : http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

Comment: you mean like a carousel? http://billwscott.com/carousel/carousel_dhtml_load_autoplay.html

Answer (score 0):

The marquee thingy is deprecated in the new standard, so I was searching around for alternatives and I came with this SO post:

[<marquee> problem in ie8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297888/marquee-problem-in-ie8)

I know this is not a solution per se, but I thought it would be helpful in some way...