# Marquee images struck in IE8 Browser Alone?

Tags: html, marquee

I use below marquee in my webpage,

```
<MARQUEE WIDTH=100% DIRECTION=LEFT BEHAVIOR=SCROLL Loop=auto BGColor=White onmouseover="this.stop()" onmouseout="this.start()" >
    <a href="http://www.berkadia.com/"><img src="/images/berkadia.png" border="0" alt="barkedia" width="200" ></a>
<a href="http://www.hcl.in"><img src="/images/hcl.png" border="0" alt="HCL" width="200"></a>
<a href="http://www.hcl-axon.com"><img src="/images/hcl-axon.png" border="0" alt="HCL-Axon" width="200"></a>
<a href="http://www.hexaware.com"><img src="/images/hexaware.png" border="0" alt="Hexaware" width="200"></a>
<a href="http://www.lebara.co.uk"><img src="/images/lebera.png" border="0" alt="Lebera" width="200"></a>
<a href="http://www.polarisft.com"><img src="/images/polaris.png" border="0" alt="Polaris" width="200"></a>
<a href="http://www.wipro.com"><img src="/images/wipro.png" border="0" alt="Wipro" width="200"></a>

                    </MARQUEE>
```

but this marquee not properly working in IE8 alone?. It marquee images but struck.

How can i Fix that?.

Comment: I refer you to this previous post:

[<marquee> problem in ie8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297888/marquee-problem-in-ie8)

Comment: I thought Marquee was deprecated.  Did you inherit web code from 1996?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no character in your marquee inner html. You have only images.
Write "&nbsp;" before every image tag